# How to get the Http Request response before rendering - Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am using Angular Universal for SSR. I want to hide the Http Request being sent from the Browser and send it from the Server. I have been trying all the possible ways but nothing is working. I got universal-starter repo from Angular and started working on it. This is the repo link with my changes - https://github.com/GowthamF/sample-universal . Hope someone can help me with this. I have been trying this for like six months.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server side you need full url

in your case
HomeComponent.ts

```
this.heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/Country/GetCountires'
```

better to implement a interceptor for your case

I just tried this dummy call, it works for me

```
this.heroesUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is api requests are visible in the network when I run the api in the local host. When I host the api in the remote server it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cant hide the user from seeing what he's doing on his own browser.

What you can do is send a token with an expiration date and only allow the request token once or more, so if some 1 wish to send that request again and again it wont be accepted.

If you final goal is to send the main request from your server, you must send a request to the server which will send main request.

Comment: I was planning to do that. But there is an issue, this application does not have login and all. So when I send the first request to get the token anyone can trace the request flow and use the same flow for them to send requests.